# Save API data to create a Javascript chart

Tags: php, autosave

I am wondering how to auto-save API data from http://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/USD and https://crypto-trade.com/api/1/ticker/dvc_btc to create a chart using jqplot.

How can I make automated calls to each of the sites every 10 minutes and save data, and not have the data be overwritten by future calls?

Something like the chart here: vircurex.com/

Comment: You need to elaborate on saving the data: Does the data need to be retained permanently? Are you familiar with mysql and json? I deal with charting and data quite a bit and would be happy to help, but need more info.

Comment: I would like to retain the data permanently.  I've JSON-encoded the data using php here: http://dvcticker.bugs3.com/json-data.php  I'm not very familiar with mysql nor cron jobs as Romin suggested below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a combination of Database , Cache and a Cron (Scheduled Job) on your server to achieve what you want to do.

A high level approach would be:
1) Run a Backend Cron Job every 10 minutes. This will make a call to your Data Source i.e. HTTP Services and save the data in the database.

2) When the front-end makes a call, you should check if the results are present in the Cache. If they are present, return from the Cache itself so that Database calls (expensive) are avoided. If the results are not present in the Cache, retrieve from Database, put in Cache and return the data.

You might want to design your Cache and the items as per your requirements. Depending on the Caching libraries that you use, you could look for features like auto-expiring the cache items, reloading them automatically, etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but could you elaborate on your answer?  I'm proficient in only HTML and CSS, so a lot of this is new to me.

Comment: The approach that I have mentioned is for the backend code. Though you could save data locally too via the Local Storage API in HTML5, I think a server side approach will suite a larger number of users. Depending on your App Server and platform (PHP, Java, Python, .NET) -- all of them have mechanisms for running a job, making network calls, database integration and caching data.

Comment: As the website is a test site, I use a free web host.  It allows me to set a cron job in the control panel, so what should I do?

Comment: I opened up a new question, so I marked your answer as the best answer.  Thanks!